# Unable to install libgtk2.0-dev on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, opencv3.0

After I type and enter the following code it will give an error saying "Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-mixing?"
$ sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev

Please tell me a solution to solve this problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by entering the command below in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get
```